# Permission issue preventing increase in Open Files Limit in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04, pam, ulimit

My Digital Ocean droplet's `ulimit -n` yields `1024`. Now it's a dedicated machine with Ubuntu 16.04, 32GB Ram, 16 Cores. I want to crank it up to `65535`.

**The problem:**

I followed a bunch of steps to configure this (given at the end). However, I run into a permission issue. Specifically:

1. Nginx `error.log` in `/var/log/nginx/` shows:
   `setrlimit(RLIMIT_NOFILE, 65535) failed (1: Operation not permitted)`
2. `auth.log` in `/var/log/` shows:
   `main-app sudo: pam_limits(sudo:session): Could not set limit for 'nofile' to soft=65535, hard=65535: Operation not permitted; uid=0,euid=0`

I am scratching my head as to how to solve this. Can an expert show me the way?

---

**Background:**

There are several guides available across the internet for increasing `ulimit -n` (and many answers on stackexchange, but none that appear to resolve this permissions issue). The steps I followed were:

i) Added `fs.file-max = 65535` in `/etc/sysctl.conf`.

ii) Ran `sudo sysctl -p` thereafter.

iii) Added the following lines in `/etc/security/limits.conf`:

```
* soft     nproc          65535
* hard     nproc          65535
* soft     nofile         65535
* hard     nofile         65535
root soft     nproc          65535
root hard     nproc          65535
root soft     nofile         65535
root hard     nofile         65535
```

iv) Added `session required pam_limits.so` to `/etc/pam.d/common-session`.

Logged out and back in. Tried rebooting and powering down and up too. `ulimit -n` won't budge from `1024`.

Comment: Good hints available here: https://ro-che.info/articles/2017-03-26-increase-open-files-limit But no clear rationale provided